# Недопустимый тип файла - проблема

Tags: html, php

Создаю поле для загрузки файлов, вот страница для загрузки картинок:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Тег INPUT, атрибут accept</title>
 </head>
 <body> 
  <form action="handler.php">
   <p><strong>Укажите картинку в формате JPEG, PNG или GIF</strong></p>
   <p><input type="file" name="img" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif">
   <input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Вот handler.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Тег INPUT, атрибут accept</title>
 </head>
 <body> 
 <?
if (empty($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])) die('Недопустимый тип файла!');
$tmp = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
$fname = $_FILES['img']['name'];
if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'wp-content/uploads/'.$fname)) die('Не удалось переместить файл из временной папки');
echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/'.$fname.'" />'; // картинка загружена
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

При загрузке любых файлов (картинки и архивы пробовал загружать) он пишет, что тип файла недопустим, хотя я же разрешил загрузку картинок:

```
<input type="file" name="img" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif">
```

В чем проблема тогда?

Comment: Посмотри php.ini включена ли у тебя опция загрузки файлов?
А именно upload_tmp_dir =

Comment: New_russian_man, должна быть включена, т.к. без ограничения на тип загрузки файлов все нормально работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У формы не указано: `method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Естественно, что get'ом не хочет отправлять файл. =)
А accept в input'е - это для удобства пользователя: некоторые браузеры ограничивают выбор файла указанными в accept.

Comment: ling, а тогда как разрешить пользователям загружать только определнный тип файлов?

Comment: Проверяйте на сервере `$_FILES['img']['type']`. mimetype'ы можно отковырять от этого класса: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/2743.html . Как я понимаю, вас интересуют все, которые начинаются на image.

Comment: Только учтите, что тип из `$_FILES['img']['type']` передается от клиента и может не соответствовать реальному типу файла. Если хотите узнать реальный тип файла, то нужно получать его непосредственно из закаченного файла, например, при помощи [fileinfo][1].

  [1]: http://php.net/fileinfo

Comment: Ну вот так можно узнать тип файла: [code]function getExtension1($filename) {
    return end(explode(".", $filename));
  }[/code] Вот я вставил этот фрагмент в handler.php и все? Больше ничего не надо?

Comment: Ну, тоже вариант. `$ext = getExtension1($_FILES['img']['name']);`, а потом - куча проверок и, если расширение файла не то, выход из скрипта.

Comment: Ясно, т.е. потом проверки типа if $etxt = *.zip, then echo "Недопустимый формат файла! Разрешено загружать только .jpg, .png, .gif и .txt!"; if $etxt = *.png, then echo "Файл успешно загружен на сервер!"?

Comment: Да, но все это в синтаксисе php.

Answer (score 1):

Подправил код, учёл ваши пожелания.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<title>Загрузка изображений</title>
</head>
<body>
<strong><label style="color:#36C;">Требования к загружаемым изображениям</label></strong><br />
1. Максимальный объём файла - 2,9 мБайт.<br />
2. Формат изображения - JPG.<br />
3. Разрешение(размер) может быть любым,<br />
   однако слишком большое изображение испортит<br />
   весь вид.
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="?l=down" method="post" />
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3000000" />
Нажмите "Обзор" или на поле ниже : <br />
<input name="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Загрузить" />
</form>
<?php
if ($_GET['l'] == 'down' ){
    $fn         =   $_FILES['name'];
    $ft         =   $_FILES['userfile'];
    $orn        =   $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $ext        =   substr($_FILES['userfile']['name'], -3);
    $allowTypes =   array ('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'txt');
    if (false !== array_search($ext, $allowTypes)) {
        $uploaddir = './wp-content/uploads/';
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            echo 'Файл загружен, ссылка ниже,&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="?">загрузить ещё</a><br />'.'<input size="40" type="text" value="'.substr($uploadfile, 1).'" /><br />';
            echo '<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(\'dimg1\').innerHTML=\'<img src=.'.substr($uploadfile, 1).' />\'" value="показать изображение" /><br />';
            echo '<div id="dimg1"></div>';
        } else {
            echo 'Файл не загружен';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Тип файла не является допустимым для загрузки';
    }
}
#
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Андрей, если загружать, например, zip архив, то он успешно загрузится, только поменяется расширение на .jpg
Меня интересует такой вариант, чтобы при загрузке изображений, все происходило нормально, а если бы человек пробовал загрузить архив, то выводилось сообщение, что тип файла недопустим и сам файл не загружался бы на сервер.

Comment: Логично, для колледжа я этого не учитывал, сейчас посмотрю. Какие типы изображений нужно разрешить загружать?

Comment: Андрей, jpg, jpeg, png, gif, ну а также еще можно txt пускай, и создание уникальных названий не нужно.

Comment: хотя, надо ещё подредактировать, проверка не правильная у меня на тип файла, чуть позже доделаю.

Comment: Андрей, хорошо, большое спасибо за помощь!